# Google OR-Tools TSP-TW the earliest time to return

Tags: or-tools

I'm working on the traveling salesman problem with time-constrained (TSP with Time Windows).
I'd like to find a solution that will give me the  earliest time to return to the depot.
However, the expected solution has not been obtained.
Specifically, it is as follows.

- I set start time to 8:00 am and end time 21:00 pm, but he proposes a plan to wait until 10:00 am at the depot, even though there are  nodes (no time-constrained) near the depot. He seems to want me to visit the near nodes at night.
  As a result, I end up returning late at night.

My request is not to reduce total travel time.
Any idea?

Comment: could you provide some code snippets ? otherwise don't hesite to ask on ortools-discuss or come on our discord (link in readme in github)

Comment: Thanks. As you say, I will post this question to "ortools-discuss".

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call the `RoutingModel::AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer()` ?

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/a0a56698ba8fd07b7f84aee4fc45d891a8cd9828/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/vrp_time_windows.py#L161-L162

Comment: Yes. I set start time and end timeby `AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer`.